# Get list of database errors on saveAll()

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a `CountryObject`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
class CountryObject(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    val id: Long? = null,

    @Column(name = "name")
    val name: String,

    @Column(name = "ISO2", length = 2)
    val ISO2: String,

    @Column(name = "ISO3", length = 3)
    val ISO3: String

) : Serializable
```

with the corresponding `PostgreSQL` create script that has some unique constraints on ISO2 and ISO3:

```
CREATE TABLE country
(
    id         BIGINT                      NOT NULL,
    name       VARCHAR(255)                NOT NULL,
    iso2       VARCHAR(2)                  NOT NULL,
    iso3       VARCHAR(3)                  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_country PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE country
    ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_ISO2 UNIQUE (iso2);

ALTER TABLE country
    ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_ISO3 UNIQUE (iso3);
```

Along with this I have a corresponding repository:

```
@Repository
interface CountryRepository : JpaRepository<CountryObject, Long>
```

And out of the box implementation of the `CountryRepository` has a `saveAll()` method that tries to insert a list of objects into the `country` table. So far, everything behaves as expected.

Once I try to insert a list that have multiple objects violating the unique constraints, the exception is thrown on the first and stopped. What I want to have is to get some list with the errors that I can use as a report, which mentions which entries failed saving. Of course nothing should be saved in that case and the transaction is rolled back.

Any hints how something like this can me achieved? Of course one option would be to try to save each object separately and then collect the errors, but that might be not that performant.

Comment: I don't think Hibernate is your friend here. Hibernate delays running inserts, updates and deletes until it must flush the transaction (usually before a `select` or before a commit). If you want to get an error from a specific insert you'll need to insert one by one and do an explicit flush between them.

Comment: The only way to get all the errors is do an insert one-by-one.